# Weblinks not working in ios 9.3.1

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode

All the links in my app to websites are no longer working. I noticed this on my iPad and iPhone a few days ago when I upgraded both to ios 9.3.1. Checked the xcode simulator on my mac (which was running under 9.3) and they did not work there either. I upgraded the mac to 9.3.1 but still no success. These links have been working for many versions of the app over several years. I've read about the issues with web links associated with 9.3 but haven't seen any reported problems with 9.3.1. Has anyone else seen this problem and have a solution?